# Prevent child elements from filling the available space flexbox

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to use a media query to display only two choco-boxes after 600px while staying responsive. I'm building mobile-first. For some reason, it continues to fill the space even when I specify a flex-basis. I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly and am looking for guidance.

I'm trying to use a media query to display only two choco-boxes after 600px while staying responsive. I'm building mobile-first. For some reason, it continues to fill the space even when I specify a flex-basis. I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly and am looking for guidance.

```
<head>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900">
</head>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>
<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div


</div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-flow: row wrap;I
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

.choco-box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  border: 2px solid #cfb56a;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h3, button {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-head {
   color: #707070;
   font-size: .9rem;
   font-weight: 600;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

button {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px 58px;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
.choco-box {
        flex: 1 0 33%;
      }
```

to your media query

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-flow: row wrap;I
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  row-gap: 30px;
 
}

.choco-box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  border: 2px solid #cfb56a;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h3, button {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-head {
   color: #707070;
   font-size: .9rem;
   font-weight: 600;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

button {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px 58px;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .choco-box {
    flex: 1 0 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900">
</head>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>
<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div>

<div class="choco-box">
  <h3 class="sub-head">Shop Ingredients You Need</h3>
  <h1 class="heading">Milk Chocolate </br>Hazelnut Bar</h1>
  <img src="https://www.godiva.com/dw/image/v2/AAKG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-godiva-master-catalog-us/default/dw22fa285f/product_images/913246-1.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Milk Chocolate Hazelnut Bar">
  
    <button value="button">Shop Now</button>
 
</div


</div>
```